# PHP library not being included, "Call to undefined function"

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to use the PHP bindings (php-wkhtmltox) for wkhtmltopdf. The README said to install libwkhtmltox and then compile php-wkhtmltox, which I've done. I've also put the compiled .so file into my PHP extension directory, and I've adjusted both my Apache and CLI php.ini files to include the extension.

Now, after reloading and even restarting Apache and running one of the test scripts included with php-wkhtmltox, I get this:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wkhtmltox_convert() in /path/to/test_pdf.php on line 3
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: does your phpinfo() say its loaded?

Comment: Negative. No mention of it in there.

Comment: Try restarting the web server? I had a similar problem installing cURL once. PHP wouldn't recognize the new module until I completely killed Apache and restarted it.

Comment: Made sure Apache was not running, restarted, and still no luck :(

Comment: Linux. Figured it out. See my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well hooray, I got it working!

I'm not exactly sure what I did to make it work, but, it was quite possibly that ldconfig was producing the following:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib/libxdiff.so.0 is not a symbolic link
```

Once I cleared this issue up (created the symlink), re-ran ldconfig, and reloaded Apache, php-wkhtmltok showed up in the phpinfo() output.

Comment: could you please guide me about this issue.. i am facing same issue.. :(

Comment: Totally don't remember how I fixed this, sorry :-/ You'll need to do some further Googling.

Comment: This is of no use to us with the same problem. We need a better explanation on how you fixed it. The only Google result leads to here...

Comment: You probably have a broken symlink. Try `ls -l /usr/local/lib/libxdiff.so.0` and check whether it points to an actual file. If not, try to find libxdiff.so -- wherever it is on your system -- and update the symlink via `ln -sf /correct/path/to/libxdiff.so /usr/local/lib/libxdiff.so.0`. If libxdiff.so isn't on your system, then you probably haven't installed libxdiff.

Comment: If that works, please add a new comment here, and I'll update my answer. Then I'd appreciate you undoing the downvote :)